# Are corona discharges any different from normal electricity?

Tags: electrically-conductive, corona

As per Wikipedia corona discharge is a electrical discharge brought on by ionization of fluid surrounding conductor. So can corona discharge be used as normal electricity like travel through wires and create magnetic fields just like normal electricity would do?Or is it not electricity at all?

Comment: Normaly we tend to suppress corona discharge. You can see weird metal toroids on the top oh HV transformers, arround wire holders of power lines, ball shaped ends of antenna...all this to suppress. So the answer is no; like we don't want a pipe that leaks water, we usually put another pipe and not accumulate the leakage.

Comment: A corona discharge *is* electricity, ergo it cannot be different from it.

Comment: No, a (corona) discharge is *not* some other form of electrical current, and not something like that energy-transporting "plasma" in Star Trek. Like light from a bulb, a discharge is a *result* of electricity and not another representation of electricity.

Comment: @JimmyB Can it travel through wires? And are there anyways to do it ?

Comment: Electrical current can travel through wires. Like light from a bulb, the corona *cannot* travel through a wire.

Comment: will it turn into a normal flow of electricity in wire?

Answer (score 1):

A corona discharge is by definition an ionization current around a conductor. The electric field around a conductor decreases in proportion to the distance from the conductor, but very local to the conductor is high enough to strip electrons off atoms of the insulating material. The corona discharge current flows radially out from the conductor, and at some distance away from the conductor drops to zero due to ion/electron recombination in the material (especially on AC power lines where the periodic reversal of electric field alternately streams electrons away from and toward the conductor) and the decrease of the electric field strength below the ionizing strength for that material.

This corona discharge is therefore an electric current conceptually flowing to ground, but it's flowing in the normally insulating material (like air) surrounding a conductor. The reason we don't call it an arc, is because the electric breakdown of the insulating material has not yet reached a point where an ionization chain-reaction has created a low-resistance path through the insulating material (a plasma). Increase the voltage on the conductor, and at some higher voltage a genuine arc discharge will occur.

You can often hear corona discharge as an kind of "electric buzz" very near high voltage power transmission lines during conditions of very high humidity, fog, rain, or snow.

Harnessing a corona discharge is very difficult (never say impossible;). If the corona discharge occurs around a high voltage conductor, one could conceive of trying to "collect" the electrons streaming away from/toward the conductor (an electric current!) with a metallic tube around the conductor (kind of like a coaxial cable). The trouble with this conceptually is that bringing the metallic tube (or any other conductor) close enough to the central conductor to actually "collect" this electron stream would actually create a breakdown of the kind that is called an arc. This would be even more undesirable than the losses due to the corona discharge, and so it's not practical way to harness the corona. Very similar to Ben Franklin flying a kit in a lightning storm: you would prove the corona is an electric current but possibly kill yourself in the process.

Answer (score 0):

A corona discharge produces ionized atoms in some cases or electrons in other cases. Both are charged particles and electric current is the flow of charged particles be they electrons or ionized atoms.

> So can corona discharge be used as normal electricity like travel
>   through wires and create magnetic fields just like normal electricity
>   would do?

I don't see why not but I don't see any advantage of this compared to the numerous disadvantages.

Comment: But is there any practical way to produce corona discharges and to send them through wires?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone doing it therefore I cannot know if there is a "practical" way to do this. Neither am I going to speculate on this without further information.

Answer (score 0):

Corona discharge is an *effect* resulting from the presence of a strong electric field. As the name suggests, it's a discharge. Energy being taken from a useful form and turned into non-useful waste light and heat. On power lines it's an unwanted side effect of electricity transmission, like a leak on a pipeline.

On the small scale, corona discharges are very useful for lighting fires. The spark of a spark plug is a corona discharge, as is that of a piezo lighter used for gas stoves.

You can't send a discharge through a wire because it would then cease to be a discharge and become normal current flow.

Comment: In [my understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge), a *corona* discharge is not the same as "electrical breakdown or arcing to nearby objects" which is used to ignite things.